# Rails code protection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to ask about techniques used for code protection for Rails app. I do know about Rubyencoder, but I wanted to know if there is any other alternative solution?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. BTW, JRuby will produce bytecode, but as with any other obfuscation technique, it can be defeated by a determined attacker.

Comment: @MarsAtomic hmm it is off-topic, seems usefull though :(

Comment: The problem is that I have to deploy the app on the customers server and want to protect it so the end-user does not have a capability to view/amend the code. I am using MRI

Comment: Let me know if my answer was useful

Answer (score 1):

**See the following other questions:**

[Obfuscating Rails app on MRI Ruby / JRuby for a enterprise customer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5357381/obfuscating-rails-app-on-mri-ruby-jruby-for-a-enterprise-customer)

[How to make server automatically push to Encrypted Git Repository after recieving Unencrypted push](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36457145/how-to-make-server-automatically-push-to-encrypted-git-repository-after-recievin)

[Encoding Ruby on Rails code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091423/encoding-ruby-on-rails-code/2091609#2091609)

[Can you Distribute a Ruby on Rails Application without Source?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/99553/can-you-distribute-a-ruby-on-rails-application-without-source/99663)